# How do I avoid getting distracted by SO notifications during the work day?

Tags: discussion

I am having a strange UX problem with SO.

The issue happens when I am working on some code of mine, and I look something up in google and end up in SO. When I land on the SO page, the first thing I see is a notification about a new message or reputation change. And invariably I click on it, and that's when I get distracted from my work. I usually spend a few minute on SO then, replying or something, and I completely forget why I was there in the first place. So I have to navigate back to my original question to remind myself what it was. It's kind of annoying. I'm here to find answers for my work most of the time, and I get sucked in the social media aspect of the site.

Has anyone the same problem? Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: This is a bit puzzling...how do you mean "derailed"?  Do you lose progress on your question entirely, such as it is no longer recoverable when you attempt to ask a new question?  Does this happen to you outside of Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Makoto: He's talking about getting distracted.

Comment: *"Any idea to avoid this?"* - don't click on it?

Comment: @Cerbrus: What I want to know from the OP is if this distraction results in lost work on the site (like the site not keeping a draft question around), or if there should be a more interpersonal meditation.  I have suggestions to the latter but want to rule out the former.

Comment: I must admit I'm very familiar with this problem - it's not a bad question as such. "Don't click on it" definitely doesn't work for me, either: when it comes to notifications I'm like a cat that sees a laser pointer. The solution seems rather obvious though.

Comment: @Makoto: basically, the distraction breaks my concentration while I am doing work. I am in a programming mindset of programming, I suddenly switch context because I am sollicited by SO. The distraction is kind of the same magnitude as if I was getting a phone call.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand the downvote, I'm just pointing out that this has been happening to me repeatedly, so that people in charge of UX know that this is a concern for at least one of their users. I mean isn't what meta is supposed to be about?

Answer (score 10):

> Any idea to avoid this?

You could log out of the site, or visit it in incognito mode whenever you're looking something up.

You could then log in explicitly whenever you actually *want* to read and reply to responses.

You could also install another browser in addition to the one you generally use, and be logged in there while you're using SO anonymously in your everyday browser.

Comment: The problem, here, of course, is that the OP may need to log back in to further their research, thus compounding the problem.

Comment: @Paul you mean because they need to post comments and such? Having a sock puppet account for the purpose could be useful, and would certainly be morally ok

Comment: And would you need a sock puppet for your sock puppet?...